# axios interceptors how to use them with axios.create()

Tags: axios, interceptor

I have the following code which I import and use in a VueJS application.

I want to be able to errors returned by the API centrally and it seems that interceptors would do the job for me but I don't understand where I set them up

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from './store/index'

export default () => {
  try{
    var token = store.state.user.token.token
  }catch(err){
    var token = ""
  }

  return axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3333/api/v1",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  })
  
}
```

I have tried this, but it does not work.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from './store/index'

axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  console.info("debug ", config);
  return config;
}, (error) => {
  console.error("debug ", error);
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

export default () => {
  try{
    var token = store.state.user.token.token
  }catch(err){
    var token = ""
  }

  return axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3333/api/v1",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  })
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some fiddling, I have worked it out.

You have to first create an axios object with `axios.create()`, then assign your intercepters to the object after which you can return the object. Here is the code I used that worked.

```
var axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3333/api/v1",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
    },
   
  })

  //This allows you to intercept the request before it is sent and alter headers or anyting else that is passed to the axios config.
  axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((config)=>{
    return config
  }, (error) => {
    console.log("Interceptor Request Error" + error)
  })

  //This allows you to intercept the response and check the status and error messages and if ncessary reject the promise.
  axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
    return response
  }, (error) => {
    console.log("Interceptor Response Error" + error)
  })
  return axiosInstance
```

Now I know how to do this, I could move my Authorization code out of the create function and put it in the request interceptor `axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use`

Comment: Hi do you face the problem like Axios is not a constructor?